# Placement of the robots.txt file for multiple domains

Tags: joomla, robots.txt, google-search-console

My website is located in a sub folder, but I assigned a domain to this sub folder so the location of the robots.txt file is www.example.com/robots.txt even though I installed Joomla in a subfolder.

Is this correct? Because Google Webmaster Tools does not list the URLs specified in the robots.txt as blocked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `example.com`, the robots.txt needs to be accessible at `example.com/robots.txt`.

It it doesn’t matter how this is accomplished on the server-side.